# I do not know what is wrong with my function. Some help would be appreciated

Tags: c++

This is the function that keeps on getting an error:

```
void displaySmallestLargestMean (intArrayTable *table, int r, int c, int maxStud)
{
  int smallest, largest;
  double mean;
  smallest = 1;
  largest = maxStud;
  for (int i = 0; i < maxStud; i++)
  {
      mean += table[i]/maxStud;
  }
  cout << "This is your Smallest Value: " << smallest << endl;
  cout << "              Largest Value: " << largest << endl;
  cout << "         Mean of the Values: " << mean << endl;
}
```

And this is my error message:

```
mainA5-255.cpp: In function ‘void displaySmallestLargestMean(int**, int, int, int)’:
mainA5-255.cpp:88:21: error: invalid operands of types ‘intArrayTable {aka int*}’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator/’
     mean += table[i]/maxStud;
```

Comment: The question is incomplete without the declaration of `intArrayTable`.

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that `intArrayTable` is of type `int*`.  The fix of course is to change the function's first parameter to `intArrayTable table`, or just ditch the pointless typedef and use `int *table`.

Answer (score 0):

In the function declaration you use `intArrayTable *table`. This means that the argument `table` is a pointer to an `intArrayTable`. Therefore, you must replace the line `mean += table[i]/maxStud;` with `mean += (*table)[i]/maxStud;`

Comment: That might not be the correct replacement.  Perhaps it goes the other way (`(*table)[i]`).  We don't know OP's intended usage.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, the declaration of `intArrayTable` would clear any ambiguity.

Comment: @RealPawPaw That was the solution, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem - please consider marking the answer as accepted. For future reference on posting for Stack Overflow, read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask